# Parse + Angular orderBy Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-orderby

I have an ng-repeat for a table in Angular. The data is coming from Parse.

```
    <tr dir-paginate="ticket in tickets | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | itemsPerPage: 10">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
        <td>{{ ticket.id }}</td>
        <td>${{ ticket.get("total").toFixed(2) }}</td>
        <td>${{ ticket.get("tax").toFixed(2) }}</td>
        <td>{{ ticket.get("paymentType") }}</td>
        <td>{{ ticket.createdAt | date: 'short' }}</td>
    </tr>
```

When I orderBy 'id' or 'createdAt' the sorting works properly. How do I go about ordering by total, tax or paymentType?

Comment: The object in question has total, tax, paymentType as attributes since it is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parse objects' attributes are accessed via `get()`, and I think `orderBy:` filter depends on having a native getter.

In angular therefore, one way to go is to create a service that extends the backbone object and provides native getters and setters:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.services').factory('MyClass', f);

    function f() {

        var MyClass = Parse.Object.extend("MyClass", {
            // instance methods

            // manually built getter like this
            attributeA : function() {
                return this.get("attributeA");
            },

        }, {
            // class methods    
        });

        // or code-built getters/setters like this
        _.each(["attributeB", "attributeC"], function(p) {
            Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, p, {
                get: function() {return this.get(p);},
                set: function(aValue) {this.set(p, aValue);}
            });
        });
        return MyClass;
    }
})();
```

This is probably good practice anyway, even if you don't need the attributes for orderBy.  The service class is a good place to put promise-returning queries, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If your data comes via Parse JavaScript SDK, you receive them as *Parse Objects* that you can convert into plain Objects more suitable for AngularJS via the `.toJSON()` method:

```
plainObject = parseObject.toJSON();
```